# Function for multiple Chi square / Fisher tests on different variables in R

Tags: r

I am working with the following data:

```
hsb2 <- within(read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsb2.csv"), {
  race <- as.factor(race)
  schtyp <- as.factor(schtyp)
  prog <- as.factor(prog)
})
```

I can perform individual chi square tests (independent variables: female and race, respectively and dependent variable: schtyp) as follows:

```
chisq.test(table(hsb2$female, hsb2$schtyp))
chisq.test(table(hsb2$race, hsb2$schtyp))
```

However, I wish to write a function that may ease the process when there are several different independent and dependent variables.

I have come up with this:

```
mychisqfunction <- lapply(hsb2[,c("female","race")], function (x) chisq.test(table(x ~ hsb2$schtyp)))
```

This function returns the error message

> Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors

Any advice on how to get this piece of code working? And any advice on how to more easily specify independent and dependent variables in the code?

Comment: Arguments in `table` are separated with a comma as you have done in your original code. Then in your `lapply` function you use a tilde `~`. Change that to a comma and it will work. `chisq.test(table(x, hsb2$schtyp))`

Comment: Thank you for your help!